# why does python loop continue work differently from other programming languages

Tags: python, loops, continue

in other programming languages when a continue is met in a loop it doesn't run the code below it and just does the next loop based on the condition set.

Yet in python it would actually not trigger the continue as much as 3 times on the same exact values until the continue actually triggers finally can someone tell me why it's like this?

function

```
def get_section(self, address):
    for section in self.sections:
        section_base = section.image_base + section.VirtualAddress
        section_end = section_base + section.Misc_VirtualSize 
        print 'section_base= 0x%x' % section_base, ' section_end = 0x%x' % section_end
        print 'VirtualAdderss = 0x%x' % section.VirtualAddress, 'Misc_virtualSize = 0x%x' % section.Misc_VirtualSize
        if address < section_base or address >= section_end:
            print 'continuued'
            continue
        print 'not continuued'
        print 'Section name = ', section.section_name
        return section
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

Here is the log

```
address = 0x4013f8

section_base= 0x401000  section_end = 0x5574e5
VirtualAdderss = 0x1000 Misc_virtualSize = 0x1564e5
not continuued
Section name =  text

address = 0x4013f8

section_base= 0x401000  section_end = 0x5574e5
VirtualAdderss = 0x1000 Misc_virtualSize = 0x1564e5
not continuued
Section name =  text

address = 0x55869c
section_base= 0x401000  section_end = 0x5574e5
VirtualAdderss = 0x1000 Misc_virtualSize = 0x1564e5
continuued

section_base= 0x558000  section_end = 0x5818ac
VirtualAdderss = 0x158000 Misc_virtualSize = 0x298ac
not continuued
Section name =  rdata
```

as you can see it didn't continue 2 times only on the 3rd time it continued and I can't figure out why shouldn't it work from the first time?

Comment: Consider logging `address`.

Comment: @bereal i'll do that

Comment: nevermind thanks bereal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two times, the `if` condition was not met; therefore the `continue` statement was not executed.